# R- Perform operations on column and place result in a different column, with the operation specified by the output column's name

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 3 columns- L1, L2, L3- of data and empty columns labeled L1+L2, L2+L3, L3+L1, L1-L2, etc. combinations of column operations. Is there a way to check the column name and perform the necessary operation to fill that new column with data?

I am thinking:
-use match to find the appropriate original columns and using a for loop to iterate over all of the columns in this search?
so if the column I am attempting to fill is L1+L2 I would have something like:
apply(dataframe[,c(i, j), 1, sum)

Comment: you can use `strsplit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems strange that you would store your operations in your column names, but I suppose it is possible to achieve:

As always, sample data helps.

```
## Creating some sample data
mydf <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)), 
                 c("L1", "L2", "L3"))

## The operation you want to do...
morecols <- c(
  combn(names(mydf), 2, FUN=function(x) paste(x, collapse = "+")),
  combn(names(mydf), 2, FUN=function(x) paste(x, collapse = "-"))
)

## THE FINAL SAMPLE DATA
mydf[, morecols] <- NA
mydf
#   L1 L2 L3 L1+L2 L1+L3 L2+L3 L1-L2 L1-L3 L2-L3
# 1  1  4  7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 2  2  5  8    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 3  3  6  9    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

One solution could be to use `eval(parse(...))` within `lapply` to perform the calculations and store them to the relevant column.

```
mydf[morecols] <- lapply(names(mydf[morecols]), function(x) {
  with(mydf, eval(parse(text = x)))
})
mydf
#   L1 L2 L3 L1+L2 L1+L3 L2+L3 L1-L2 L1-L3 L2-L3
# 1  1  4  7     5     8    11    -3    -6    -3
# 2  2  5  8     7    10    13    -3    -6    -3
# 3  3  6  9     9    12    15    -3    -6    -3
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Quick question about the syntax- so eval evaluates expressions only, so you are using parse to create an expression from a string?

Comment: @user2631296, Pretty much. The output of `parse` is an `expression`, but it is not evaluated, hence the need for `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

```
dfrm <- data.frame( L1=1:3, L2=1:3, L3=3+1,  `L1+L2`=NA, 
                   `L2+L3`=NA, `L3+L1`=NA, `L1-L2`=NA, 
                    check.names=FALSE)
dfrm
#------------
  L1 L2 L3 L1+L2 L2+L3 L3+L1 L1-L2
1  1  1  4    NA    NA    NA    NA
2  2  2  4    NA    NA    NA    NA
3  3  3  4    NA    NA    NA    NA
#-------------
 dfrm[, 4:7] <- lapply(names(dfrm[, 4:7]), 
                       function(nam) eval(parse(text=nam), envir=dfrm) )
 dfrm
#-----------
  L1 L2 L3 L1+L2 L2+L3 L3+L1 L1-L2
1  1  1  4     2     5     5     0
2  2  2  4     4     6     6     0
3  3  3  4     6     7     7     0
```

I chose to use `eval(parse(text=...))` rather than `with`, since the use of `with` is specifically cautioned against in its help page. I'm not sure I can explain why the `eval(..., target_dfrm)` form should be any safer, though.